# Ubuntu Server Live CD installation stuck at purple screen!

Tags: boot, system-installation

I recently formatted my windows 7 hard drive. I wanted to instal Ubuntu server 32-bit version so i can host some files. I burnt the Iso image to a blank cd to boot the computer from there. When I went to the installation page i selected my language and keyboard. Then it started to scan my hardware. As soon as it finished scanned CD-ROM, it got stuck at a purple screen with a white line underneath. I am very frustrated why this is not working. (Note: before the installation booted, it showed this PCI BIOS error and then it booted to installation page). I am open to any suggestions.
Thanks.